# how does the overflow value gets evaluated upon crossing max int datatype value

Tags: c#

How does the below code generatesthe output -2147483648.I know int.maxvalue is 2147483647.

```
     class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int i = int.MaxValue;
                i += 1;
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
```

Comment: That behavior is called overflow.

Comment: just want to know the behavior of the output in such cases .

Comment: It is a signed integer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 3):

The `int` uses 32 bits to store its number. Thus the stored number can only be so large. You start `i` with the maximum value. So when you add 1, the underlying representation of the `int` can't hold that number. This is called overflow.

There isn't any extremely satisfying answer for why you get `-2147483648`.  When you add `1` to `int.MaxValue`, you have to get *something*. Side effects of the way `int` is formatted in memory ([Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)) is the reason you get this particular negative number when the overflow happens.

You can use the `checked` keyword around operations that might overflow to get an exception if this happens. See here: [checked (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = int.MaxValue;
        try
        {
            checked
            {
                i += 1;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        catch (OverflowException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Overflow!");
        }
    }
}
```

To use this you'll have to enable the `/checked` compiler option. See here: [Checked and Unchecked (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khy08726.aspx)

Comment: then how does 2147483647 becomes -2147483648 ? Does it try to add something here ?

Comment: For completeness, `checked` is also a global compiler switch - it defaults to `unchecked`, hence why `GetHashCode()` in OSS code should include `unchecked`, just in case the user is running in `checked` mode and compiles it